# jqModal : launching multiple modal dialogs not working in Safari

Tags: jquery, jqmodal

When I have only one modal dialog It works in Safari too. In this case I am using default jqModal selectors as shown below

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="jqModal">Start Demo 1</a>

<div class="jqmWindow" id="dialog"> Demo 1 </div>
```

JS

```
$('#dialog').jqm({modal:true});
```

But when I add multiple links to open separate dialogs, it doesn't work in safari.
It works on all other browsers.

HTML code for multiple dialogs

```
<a id="startDemo1" href="#">
  <h3 class="demo-heading">Demo 1</h3>
</a>
<div id="Demo1" class="jqmWindow">
  <p>Demo 1</p>
</div>

<a id="startDemo2" href="#">
  <h3 class="demo-heading">Demo 2</h3>
</a>
<div id="Demo2" class="jqmWindow">
  <p>Demo 2 Let's see if it launches new dialog</p>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

    $('div.jqmWindow').jqm({modal:true, overlay: 50, trigger: false})

    $('#startDemo1').click(function() {
        $('#Demo1').jqmShow();
        return false;
    });

    $('#startDemo2').click(function() {
        $('#Demo2').jqmShow();
        return false;
    });

});
```

Please let me know if you have any solution or a better way to implement multiple modal dialogs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wanted to correct the JS code I posted

```
$('div.jqmWindow').jqm({modal:true, overlay: 50, trigger: false})
```

should have been

```
$("Demo1").jqm({modal:true, overlay: 50, trigger: false})
$("Demo2").jqm({modal:true, overlay: 50, trigger: false})
```

But I still can't get the 2 modal dialogs launched on Safari.

All other browsers are working. They were somehow working even with the wrong JS earlier.